# Available memory low despite no process using a lot of memory

Tags: 22.04, ram, memory-usage, htop, free

so I fired up my personal Ubuntu 22.04 server today, and noticed that it was extremely slow in comparison to yesterday. I checked via commands what was going on and am really confused:

[image]

As you can see here, "available" is extremely low. With htop:

[image]

This is sorted by memory usage. Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but it seems to me as if there is no available memory, yet no process is using more than 0.2% (which I would assume is normal).

Do any of you have an idea what could be going on here? The server is so slow, I can't even run something like "neofetch".

Comment: Your Jemkins java thingy seems to be using 12 - 13 Gig according to htop ,,,

Comment: Are you referring to the virtual memory size of Jenkins? I dont think that is the issue, as the process itself holds barely 13mb of actual RAM. Also, I've made no changes to Jenkins since last night. Furthermore, even if I stop all jenkins' processes, I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sync; echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Maybe your page cache is not clearing?

sync - Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage

https://serverfault.com/questions/520490/very-high-memory-usage-but-not-claimed-by-any-process

Comment: Thank you so much! While your suggestion didn't solve my problem, the link helped a lot. For others with a similar problem: my issue was solved by setting "/proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages" to 0.